# SQL count duplicate by row value

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

```
user_id | hash 
user1  |   a1 
user1  |   a1
user2  |   b2
user2  |   b3
user2  |   b2
user2  |   b3
user3  |   a3
user3  |   a5
```

I have a table like the above. I am trying to find out how many duplicates hashes exist per user. I'm still a newbie to sql.

Trying to generate something like the following to count how many duplicate hashes exist per user

```
user_id | duplicates hash count
user1  |   2 
user2  |   4
user3  |   0
```

Thinking something along this query, but I can't figure out how to count duplicates for each  user, not across the entire table

```
SELECT COUNT(hash) AS count 
FROM TABLE GROUP BY id_hash HAVING (count > 1)
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Hint: `HAVING` is for aggregate function conditions!

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance. Also add a tag for the dbms you're using.

Comment: show expected output, so it will be easier to understand what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below approach

```
select user_id, countif(dup) as duplicates_hash_count
from (
  select *, 1 < count(*) over(partition by user_id, `hash`) dup
  from your_table
)
group by user_id
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Different ways to do it:

```
with agg as (
    select user_id, hash, count(*) as cnt
    from T
    group by user_id
    having count(*) > 1
)
select user_id, sum(cnt) as dup_total
from agg
group by user_id;

with agg as (
    select *, count(*) over (partition by user_id, hash) as cnt
    from T
)
select distinct user_id, sum(cnt) over (partition by user_id) as dup_total
from agg
where cnt > 1;
```

I think the first is most straightforward. Find the hashes with duplicates and eliminate the others. Report that count and then total up by user id.